# "typename" and "template" keywords: are they really necessary?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, keyword, typename

There are a lot of questions at this site with the problems while compiling c++ template code. One of the most common solutions to such problems is to add `typename` (and, less frequently, `template`) keyword in the right places of the program code:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:

    typedef char SomeType;

    template<typename U>
    void SomeMethod(SomeType& v)
    {
        // ...
    }

};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:

    void Method()
    {
        typename Base<T>::SomeType x;
    //  ^^^^^^^^

        this->template SomeMethod<int>(x);
    //        ^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

Whether there is a code that compiles both with and without keyword `typename` and gives different results (e.g. output strings)? Similar question for `template` keyword.

If not, whether these keywords are really necessary in such meanings?

#### A small overview of the current situation

[**@Paul Evans**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312406/paul-evans) wrote a good answer but it is more suitable for the question ["Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords), not for my question.

[**@Simple**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491746/simple) gave an example of [the required code for `typename` keyword](http://ideone.com/ewfn0Q) and [its possible variation](http://ideone.com/XiWlXs). [**@Jarod42**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) gave [another variation without any templates](http://ideone.com/iuq0AT), which is probably a *gcc* bug because it [does not compile with *clang*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe4ff0bf6c9eefeb).

[**@n.m.**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) gave an example of [the required code for `template` keyword](http://ideone.com/UIqrtb), [**@dyp**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) [improved it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a051325f703b097c). [**@n.m.**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) also wrote [the another code for both keywords](http://ideone.com/mEhajk) using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

[**@James Kanze**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) in his answer argues that it is impossible to write the required code and any attempts to do it will result in undefined behavior. So the above examples of code are illegal.

**It is interesting to find out who is right and what the C++ standard says about this.**

Comment: Maybe read up about these keywords beforehand? They are related to name lookup and dont have a semantically meaning.

Comment: Consider `f < 5 > (25);`. How is this parsed? It could be some weird comparison `(f>5) > 25` or a function call `f<5> (25)`. Similarly, `X::m * p;` could be a declaration (of `p`) where `X::m` is a type, or it could be an expression involving a static data member `X::m` times some previously declared `p`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ewfn0Q

Comment: @Simple You could even write `auto x = B::bar(10);` vs. `auto x = typename B::bar(10);`.

Comment: @Paranaix Possibly my question is silly enough. And of course I know what are they used for.

Comment: @dyp Yes, I know what the problems compiler is experienced without these keywords while parsing c++ code.

Comment: @Simple Greate! And what about `template` keyword?

Comment: @Simple thats nice - pull it into this

Comment: It's harder to come up with a similar example for `template`.

Comment: @Simple Except that that is illegal code (resulting in undefined behavior).  When you write `typename B::bar`, the compiler assumes that `bar` names a type, but when you instantiate the template, `bar` names a function; the `struct bar` should _not_ be found by the lookup.

Comment: @Simple Please, post your code as an answer.

Comment: @JamesKanze http://ideone.com/XiWlXs better?

Comment: http://ideone.com/UIqrtb Feel free to improve.

Comment: @Simple It suffers from exactly the same problem.  By definition, it is impossible to create a program that would be legal both with and without the `typename`, and have different, but defined semantics in both cases; it is perfectly legal (but not desirable) for a compiler to defer parsing the template until instantiation, and to totally ignore the `typename` or `template`.  If this would result in something different than a compiler which actively used them, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: what about http://ideone.com/iuq0AT ? There is no template.

Comment: @n.m. Without any `reinterpret_cast`s: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a051325f703b097c

Comment: @Jarod42 *main.cpp:11:22: error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'baz' in 'widget'* http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe4ff0bf6c9eefeb

Comment: Does the example with template is valid ? According to @JamesKanze's answer, it should not be...

Comment: @n.m. Interesting code, thank you.

Comment: @Jarod42 What example did you mean?

Comment: @Constructor: I mean the [dyp's one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a051325f703b097c) for example (with the keyword `template`).

Comment: @JamesKanze even if the examples provided are invalid, there's another class of examples: those that involve SFINAE. In this case your argument doesn't work.

Comment: @Jarod42 Clearly, thanks. I want to know JamesKanze is right or not, too.

Comment: @n.m. Can you give such examples (using SFINAE), please?

Comment: @Constructor http://ideone.com/mEhajk g++ does not accept one of the calls (commented out in the code), but clang++ does. I thing g++ is in the wrong here. Anyway the rest of the calls look pretty much valid.

Comment: @n.m. Brilliantly! Thank you. I think this code could refute James Kanze's point of view.

Comment: @n.m. Ah! It's entirely possible that there could be something
involving SFINAE; I've not studied it in detail.  But maybe.
I suppose it depends on how you interpret "the specified member
is not a type where a type is required"; is a type required
because the name was qualified by `typename`?  (I think the
undefined behavior occurs before the compiler gets here, but
it's really not very clear.)

Comment: @n.m. The example is very good.  I'm not sure what to think about it, however: undefined behavior, or required behavior corresponding to that of clang?  I think you can read the standard two ways.

Comment: Re the summary: there is no doubt that the examples in the question here are undefined behavior.  The one involving SFINAE, on the other hand?  I think the standard is ambiguous in its regard; one could interpret it either way.

Comment: @JamesKanze What parts of the standard do you mean?

Comment: I think that passing object to variadic function is UB, though (in the SFINAE example).. (@Constructor: comment move correctly, and variadic function are functions with `...` (as `printf`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 I know what variadic functions are. :-) As I understand your previous comment got wrong place and it seemed very strange to me.

Comment: @Jarod42 The code can be simply corrected to prevent UB. It is sufficient that the nonvariadic variant of function would take a pointer rather than a value (as its second argument). And pass something like `(S<sizeof(xxx)>*)nullptr` or `(S<sizeof(xxx)>*)0` instead of `S<sizeof(xxx)>()`.

Comment: You might be interested in my comments on @JamesKanze's answer

Comment: @JamesKanze why is UB involved, because you say "I think the undefined behavior occurs before the compiler gets here, but it's really not very clear."?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Interesting information, thank you.

Comment: @james The text that says "the specified member is not a type where a type is required" is in a note and has no real significance.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm not too sure myself.  If you have `typename A::B` in the template (where `A` is a template parameter), and when you instantiate, `B` does _not_ name a type, the program is ill formed.  This is not an error ignored by SFINAE.  On thinking it over, however...  If substitution failure occurs, the template is not instantiated, so what happens when you instantiate can't be an issue.

Comment: @JamesKanze what do you mean by "error ignored by SFINAE"? A type that is ill-formed when written using the substituted template arguments causes deduction to fail and triggers the "SFINAE case", not a hard compiler error. And the `typename A::B` case certainly looks like such an "SFINAE case" to me. I see no difference at all to the case where `B` doesn't exist at all. In both cases we have an error and trigger the SFINAE case.

Comment: I agree that "If a specialization of a template is instantiated for a set of template-arguments such that..." requires an instantiation, but SFINAE prevents such. But therefor the Standard says "An invalid type or expression is one that **would** be ill-formed...", so the SFINAE can try to see whether the instantiation would work and use the rules governing it, without actually doing it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's basically what I said, in the end.  My initial analysis was a bit different, but I've changed my mind about it.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is: `typename` *has* to be used whenever a name that depends on a template parameter is a type.  There *are* clear cases where it's needed, consider

```
template <typename T> 
class Foo { 
    typename T::type * p; 
    //... 
};
```

Here, the second `typename` is used to indicate that `type` is a type defined within `class T`. Thus, `p` is a pointer to the type `T::type`.

Without `typename`, `type` would be considered a member of `class T`. So the expression:

```
T::type * p
```

would be a multiplication of the `type` member of `class T` with `p`.

Similarly, the rule is: `.template`, `->template` or `::template` *must* be used when accessing a template member that uses a template parameter. Consider:

```
 p->template SomeMethod<int>(x);
```

without the use of `template`, the compiler does not know that the `<` token is not *less-than* but the start of a *template argument list*.

Comment: and what about the template?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the answer to my question. See the code which @Simple gave in the comments of the question.

Comment: Sometimes you even need both, like `typename widget::template apply<gadget>`.

Comment: I think the answer is complete and should be accepted

Comment: @piotruś It is the complete answer, but not for _my_ question.

Comment: @Constructor please explain what it lacks or what is unclear yet, and maybe author will enhance it

Comment: @piotruś As I wrote this answer is good and complete enough. But it corresponds to the response to the question "Where keywords `typename` and `template` are needed to be used?" I know where. My question was different. See the code which @Simple gave in the comments to the question to understand what I really want.

Comment: Interesting. But how is this different from the non-template case? I.e., if Foo is a type, "Foo::type * p;" is OK, but if T is a typename template, "T::type * p;" requires the "template" keyword to remove an ambiguity?

Comment: @Igorostrovsky because the compiler *knows* all about Foo and therefore all of its members.  Where as T is a placeholder of a yet-to-be determined type.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, it is impossible to write code which differs in
meaning with or without the keyword; any attempt to do so will
result in undefined behavior.  The only purpose of these
keywords (at least in this context) is to allow the compiler to
fully parse the template before instantiation: in order to
correctly parse C++, the compiler must know whether a symbol
designates a type, a template or something else.

Once you instantiate the template, the compiler no longer really
needs the keywords; they have no impact on name lookup, or
anything else.  The only particularity is that if the name found
puts a lie to your declaration (you said type, and in the
instantiation, it isn't a type), undefined behavior occurs.  If,
for example, the compiler has stored the template in the form of
a parse tree, this parse tree will be incorrect, and who knows
what that might imply.

I would expect that most good compilers would note the category
in the first parse, and if name lookup returns something else,
emit an error, but for historical reasons, I suspect that there
are still compilers which more or less ignore the `template` or
`typename` in this context, treating it as a comment; store the
template as a sequence of tokens, and only parse once the
template is instantiated, using the categories it actually finds
in the instantiation.

EDIT:

I've been rereading parts of the standard, and I'm no longer
sure that there is undefined behavior.  C++11, at least, says:

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type
>   unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name
>   is qualified." by the keyword typename.
>
> When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not
>   a member of the current instantiation and its
>   nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be
>   prefixed by the keyword typename, forming
>   a typename-specifier.  If the qualified-id in
>   a typename-specifier does not denote a type, the program is
>   ill-formed.

Ill-formed usually (but not always) requires a diagnostic.  (As
mentioned above, I would expect a compiler to issue a diagnostic
in any case.)

Comment: Can you support your words with quotations from standard? Why the codes of Simple, n.m are not right in accordance with standard? Thank you.

Comment: Both clang++ and g++ do something else. They apparently parse the template, store the name category, and when an instantiation is made, search for the name only within its associated category. If e.g. it was `typename x` and in the actual instantiation there are both a type member and a non-type member named `x`, the type member is taken, even if in the non-template case the non-type one would be taken. It is not clear to me whether the standard sanctions such behaviour or not.

Comment: @n.m. Well, if you lied, it's undefined behavior, so whatever the compiler does is "correct".

Comment: As far as I know, clang correctly finds the non-type name even with `typename` (so, it indeed has no impact on name lookup for clang, unlike `class`). GCC doesn't, and it is because of this bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48920 . I don't think it is undefined behavior in the non-template case. And in the template case, I think it is an SFINAE-case in SFINAE contexts, so compilers can't just ignore the rules.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes.  I hadn't thought about the context of SFINAE.  I'm not sure what the implications are, because I'm not sure of the order of the different steps the compiler is required to take.  Finding a non-type when something is declared with a `typename` isn't one of the errors which SFINAE ignores (or at least, it's not in the list).  On the other hand, finding a non-type means that the instantiation fails, so the template won't be instantiated (and if it isn't instantiated, there can't be a mismatch between the instantiation and the template).

Comment: @Constructor The whole issue is interesting.  I don't find the standard particularly easy to understand here, and I'm curious as to how it should be interpreted.